# Bind to Style Setter from a different Style

Tags: c#, wpf

how do I go about binding the Foreground Colour of one Style setter to the Fill Colour on another Style Setter, it should be the same object type. This is the code I have got below!

Getting these errors:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=MenuItemPath'. BindingExpression:Path=Fill;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemName" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ElementName=MenuItemPath, Path=Fill}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItem" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Path" x:Name="MenuItemPath">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF22252C" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="25" />
                <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would create a separate Resource for storing the brush color, and reference it from both locations.

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF22252C" x:Key="MenuFillColor" /> 

<Style x:Key="MenuItemName" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MenuFillColor}" />
    ...
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItem" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Path" x:Name="MenuItemPath">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource MenuFillColor}" />
            ...
        </Style>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
</ControlTemplate>
```

That said, I've never actually tried binding to another Style's Setter.Value property... it might be possible assuming everything was the same scope. You look like you may have different scopes since you are using `<ControlTemplate.Resources>` to limit the scope of your MenuItemPath style to just that ControlTemplate. But personally I would not attempt it, and would assume any requirement that needed something like this could also be done some better way :)

Comment: Hmm, the idea is the Path and the Foreground will be the same colour, but the path colour is changed by triggers depending if the RadioButton IsChecked.

Comment: @MartynBall In that case, you need to bind to the `Path.Fill` property that the template is applied to. The Style's `Setter.Value` property won't change when the trigger changes the `Path.Fill` property. I'm not sure what your code looks like, but if you want to update your question with the code showing the control the template is applied to, and where in relation to it the Style is I could try to make a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access outer property of another style in wpf and that's why you have got binding error. Rather you can declare a color in your resources and from where you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

I was making it more complicated than need be, I just added a DataTrigger which fixed the issue:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemName" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MenuItemRadio}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```